# Combining content breaks category pagination

Tags: pagination

I'm trying to combine two types of content in a category archive, essentially injecting a second stream of content into the archive, but I can't get pagination to work. Say I have 15 posts, and 10 of a second type (lets call it 'stream'). If posts_per_page is set to 20, it will show the first 20 combined, but the second page doesn't exist and I get a 404. I know the obvious way to do this is using the pre_get_posts hook, and modifying the query before it gets run. Problem is the second type of content is a custom table (not my idea, helping a coworker) and it would be a ton of work to update it to a post type.

I've already worked through all the filters and actions that are called on the category archive, and nothing makes subsequent pages show. Using the found_posts filter, I've returned the combined count if on a category archive, but that doesn't work. If I set found_posts in pre_get_posts, I can see by printing $wp_query that max_num_pages gets updated to the correct value, but I still get a 404.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The post_type parameter for WP_Query can accept an array of post types. This would allow you to combine both streams into a single query which should resolve your current dilemma with pagination.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => array('page','post') ) );
```

Comment: The second post type is a custom table, not a custom post type.

Comment: Ah, my apologies for missing that in your original question. Rethinking.

Comment: I don't think native WP pagination is going to work with the custom table in the mix. I believe the 404 stems from WordPress trying to calculate a second page where the numbers aren't adding up properly. To work around this you might try setting up a custom variable, passed as a unique query string or URL pattern. When the category page sees this parameter you should be able to modify the view to reflect a second page of results. I'll provide a code example in a new answer when I get back to my desk.